# PHP spl autoload classes not autoloading

Tags: php, php-8.1, spl-autoload-register

I'm trying to use the SPL autoloader in php 8.1 but getting the bellow error.

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected identifier "Router", expecting "{" in index.php on line 54`

I have tested this in similar environments but on different versions of php and less than 8.1 all run perfectly fine. So the issue is unique to 8.1.

I can't seem to find anything other than the old autoloader function being depreciated on the docs which was to be replaced with spl.

I can't help but feel it's a syntax error specific to 8.1 and not actually anything to do with the spl autoloader. But again I've tried various things and just can't seem to get to the bottom of it.

Doe's anyone know of a specific reason why this may be happening?

Bellow is the code I'm using. Which again works in less than 8.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class Init {
    
    function __construct() {

        define( 'APPS_PATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
        
                // Get params
        $this->page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 'Home';
        $this->action = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['action'] : false;
            
    }
    
    public function get_page(){
        
        return $this->page;
        
    }
    
    public function get_action(){
        return $this->action;
    }

    public static function register() {
        spl_autoload_register( function ( $class ) {
            $class = str_replace( '\\', '/', $class );
            $class = str_replace( '/\s+/', '', $class );
            $file = APPS_PATH . $class . '.php';
            
            if ( file_exists( $file ) ) {
                // Check for Clas Introduction : echo '['.$file.']'.PHP_EOL;
                require_once ( $file );
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } );
    }
    
}

$init = new Init();

$init->register();

// Routing to operation
use routing\ Router as Router;

$router = new Router();

$router->go_to_page($init->get_page());
```

Comment: Is that code block one file? Because `use routing\Router as Router;` must be at the start of file. And you dont need the `as Router` part. Its only used if you want an alias like `use routing\Router as MyRouter;`

Comment: @Foobar The alias is needed in order to call the class later as just router and not routing\ Router. also it can't be at the start as SPL needs initiated first and it doesn't have to be. I also have pretty much this exact same setup on several different servers. Which works fine. The only difference is in this case its run by apache2.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the autoloader, is just syntax. PHP 8 changes, see the earlier answer, the space is not allowed any longer.

Comment: @hakre Yeah, I'm going to have to change my code tidyer to not do that now. I had been up and down the doc and misses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra space here:

```
use routing\ Router as Router;
```

It should be:

```
use routing\Router as Router;
```

---

This is a change in PHP 8 syntax:

> Namespaced names can no longer contain whitespace: While Foo\Bar will be recognized as a namespaced name, Foo \ Bar will not. Conversely, reserved keywords are now permitted as namespace segments, which may also change the interpretation of code: new\x is now the same as constant('new\x'), not new \x().

([ref](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php))

Comment: Hi Pavel, Thanks for the answer and the reference. I can see it now in the docs.